# line up in Scala apps for console

Tags: scala

Doing `print("\033[F")` works to go a line up in the console, but the (Scala 2.11.6) compiler complains about

```
warning: Octal escape literals are deprecated, use \u001b instead.
```

However print("\u001b") doesn't seem to have any effect. How to do this correctly in Scala?

Comment: Have you tried `print("\u001b[F")`?

Comment: Thank you! That worked. You may add this as an answer, if you like ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: `\u001b` is the same as the deprecated `\033`, so the whole string should be `"\u001b[F"`